# Can tar extract jar files

Tags: tar, java, archive

From https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-how-to-create-executable-fatjar-without-ide

```
tar xf ExecutableOne.jar
```

but why do I get

```
$ tar xf ExecutableOne.jar 
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because `jar` files are not tar archives, and it's utterly bewildering to me that that article suggests they are.

Comment: This is probably a typo in the article, which really meant to say `jar xf` rather than `tar xf`.

Comment: They *are* just zip files, though, so you can extract them with `unzip` too.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Can tar extract zip files?

Comment: I wouldn’t be surprised if there were an implementation that could, but not usually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A jar file is a Java ARchive, not a tarball that can be extracted. You can install jar or java and extract the files (or use 7-Zip), but you can't extract them with tar.

Comment: rename your jar to .zip `mv myjar.jar myjar.zip` , then `unzip myjar.zip`

Answer (score 6):

`bsdtar` (which is the regular `tar(1)` on FreeBSD, and easily installable on Linux) can extract `.jar`s transparently, and a lot of other archive formats.

`.jar`s are basically `.zip` files.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are old enough to remember, it USED to work (at least on Solaris) just fine:  you could use tar to enumerate and extract the contents of a .jar file.  It was extremely handy for double checking for the presence of specific .class files on a target system, where you typically didn't have developer tools deployed.